# template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected "=" in operand

Tags: windows, docker, go, go-templates, docker-command

```bash
template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected "=" in operand
```

I got the above error when executing the below command in Windows,

```bash
docker inspect --format="{{range $key, $value := .Config.Env}}{{if eq (index (split $value "=") 0) "VERSION"}}{{$value}}{{end}}{{end}}" octopusbi-agent-backend
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `"="` symbol, if you use a double quotation(`"`) mark inside the string enclosed with the double quotation(`"`) marks, you have to add a backslash(`\`) before every double quotation(`"`) mark excluding the first and last double quotation(`"`) mark.

example:-

```bash
"Hello "your_name""  <-- wrong
"Hello \"your_name\""  <-- correct
```

---

## Windows

As I mentioned earlier I changed `"="` to `\"=\"` and after that, I got another issue related to some other string value called `"VERSION"`. For that also I had to change `"VERSION"` to `\"VERSION\"` and it worked as I expected.

[image]

So the final command is,

```bash
docker inspect --format="{{range $key, $value := .Config.Env}}{{if eq (index (split $value \"=\") 0) \"VERSION\"}}{{$value}}{{end}}{{end}}" octopusbi-agent-backend
```

## Ubuntu

I ran the same command in Ubuntu with the starting and ending quotations with single quotation(`'`) marks and kept the rest of the double quotation(`"`) marks.

[image]

So the final command is,

```bash
docker inspect --format='{{range $key, $value := .Config.Env}}{{if eq (index (split $value "=") 0) "VERSION"}}{{$value}}{{end}}{{end}}' octopusbi-agent-backend
```

---

#### Summary

If you use the `docker inspect` command with the `--format` option,

- In Windows:-

  1. You have to start the format string with double quotation(`"`) marks.
  2. If you want to use a double quotation(`"`) mark inside the format string, use `\"` instead.
- In Ubuntu:-

  1. You have to start the format string with single quotation(`'`) marks.
  2. Feel free to use double quotation(`"`) marks inside the format string.

In the shortest, we have to use the double quotation(`"`) mark inside the format string for both environments if you need to use the quotation mark.